# pdb from base class, get inside a method of derived class

Tags: python, debugging, inheritance, pdb

I need to use `pdb.set_trace()` in the base class. It has a method:

```
def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
    raise NotImplementedError
```

Since this base class is derived by many subclasses I don't know before hand which class' `run()` method I need to get inside. Also there is some pre processing of the arguments given to the `run()` method. 
So when pdb reaches the line,

`q=self.run(arguments)`

and I hit `s` it acts as if I have given the command `next`.

How can I get inside the derived class' `run()` method with pdb and debug the code over there?

Comment: Could you please be more clear for e.g. in which IDE you are trying to debug and what message/error are you getting? Your question is not clear as of now.

Answer (score 0):

It works absolutely fine if this example satisfies your problem:

**base.py:**

```
class basebase():
    print("something")
    def fun(self):
        print("hello")
    def getobj(obj):
        obj.fun()
print("run")
```

**intermediate.py:**

```
from base import basebase
class inter(basebase):
    print("nothing")
```

**derived.py:**

```
from intermediate import inter
class der(inter):
    def fun(self):
        print("world")
```

**main.py:**

```
from derived import der
from base import basebase
obj=der()
basebase.getobj(obj)
```

Now simply add `pdb.set_trace` to the `getobj()` method. Problem solved!